# Adding InheritInChildApplications to web.config causes an 500 server error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I added to my web.config file.

```
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        .....
    </location>
</configuration>
```

After I added that to my web.config file. I got a generic error that says "There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. asp.net"

I turn off customError and I still see the same error message.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Do you see the error from the parent page (where you changed the web.config), or in a page that is a child of the parent?  For one, you've not closed your <location /> element, so your web.config structure could be entirely invalid.  Or perhaps some child actually needs the configuration resource you are restricting?

Comment: I see the error from the parent page. Yes I did close the location tag.

Comment: Your example doesn't close the tag though.  Where you have closed it matters.  For example, is your closing </location> outside of </configuration>?

Comment: Sorry I updated my example.  Its inside the </configuration> tag so its "</location></configuration>".  I copied that from my web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in how you are specifying path=".".

Assuming you wish to restrict the current directory and all root directories, you can simply omit the path property altogether:

```
<location inheritInChildApplications="false"> .... </location>
```

Comment: I removed the path and I am still getting the 500 error :/

Comment: What should the path directory be? Why is it there?